# Python is reading rows from a CSV file out of order on Windows 7 corporate laptop - what could be the issue?

Tags: python, windows, csv, salesforce

I have a Python script that is creating a CSV file named 'reader.csv' with queried data from Salesforce for staging purposes. It then sends the data, reads the data from 'reader.csv' row by row and writes this row to our output file. For some context, it needs to use a staging file to manipulate the array indexes in each row based off of certain values to place them elsewhere in the output file (grabbing the Mortgage Status Date values and placing that same date in accordance to the column headers).

On a Windows 7 corporate machine, the script is reading the array from each row in the 'reader.csv' file out of order... which means it's writing to the output file out of order. It has been tested on several Macs, a newer Windows 10 machine, and even a Raspberry Pi running an old Linux distro... and it all works perfectly. Yet, when we run the script on a Windows 7 machine, it reads the data from the staging file out of order and then writes it out of order in the output file. Here is my code that extracts the data and then writes it to the corresponding CSV files (alongside the transform method I'm using to manipulate the dictionary:

```
def sf_extract(sf_object, query):
    """ Queries Salesforce objects and returns the data in an 
    OrderedDict """

    # Define the job and object, then query the data
    job = sf.create_query_job(sf_object, contentType='CSV')
    batch = sf.query(job, query)
    sf.close_job(job)

    # Waits to make sure the query has been fetched
    while not sf.is_batch_done(batch):
        time.sleep(10)

    # Decode the results
    for result in sf.get_all_results_for_query_batch(batch):
        data = unicodecsv.DictReader(result, encoding='utf-8')

    return data

def csv_writer(sf_object, data):
    """ Creates a 'Reader' file, transforms the data, then writes 
    the transformed data to an output file """

    file_name = "contact_product_data " + str(year_month_day) + ".csv"

    # Opens a CSV file
    with open("reader.csv", 'a+', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as in_file:

        # Grabs each item (record dictionary) from the data and loops through it
        for item in data:
            # Logic to get rid of records that are not owned by Loan Officer's
            if item["Owner.Id"] in users_list:
                item = data_transform(sf_object, item)
                writer = csv.DictWriter(in_file, item.keys())
                writer.writerow(item)

    with open("reader.csv", 'r+', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as in_file, open(file_name, 'w+', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as out_file:
        reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(config.csv_header)

        for row in reader:
            print(row)
            try:
                status = row[28]
                date = row[29]
                if str(status) in config.milestone_keys:
                    row[config.milestone_index[status]] = str(date)
            except:
                writer.writerow(row)
            else:
                writer.writerow(row)

def data_transform(sf_object, item):
    """ Take the results of a query job and transform the data 
    (append
    a "Contact Type" header and value, depending on the Salesforce 
    object). """

    item = OrderedDict(item)

    if sf_object == "Bank_Account__c":
        item["Mortgage_Status_Date__c"] = (item["Mortgage_Status_Date__c"])[:-14]
        item.update({'Contact Type':'Client'})
        item.move_to_end('Contact Type', last=False)
        item.update({'Lead Source':''})
        item.move_to_end('Lead Source', last=False)
        item.update({'App Received':''})
        item.update({'Submitted to Underwriting':''})
        item.update({'Initial/Conditional Approval':''})
        item.update({'Clear to Close':''})
        item.update({'Funded':''})
        item.update({'Denied':''})
        item.update({'Withdrawn':''})
        del item["Owner.Id"]
        if item["Opportunity__r.LeadID__c"]:
            item["Primary_Customer__r.Id"] = item["Opportunity__r.LeadID__c"]
        del item["Opportunity__r.LeadID__c"]
    if sf_object == "Lead":
        item.update({'Contact Type':'Lead'})
        item.move_to_end('Contact Type', last=False)
        item.update({'Lead Source':item["LeadSource"]})
        item.move_to_end('Lead Source', last=False)
        del item["LeadSource"]
        del item["Owner.Id"]
    if sf_object == "Opportunity":
        item.update({'Contact Type':'Lead'})
        item.move_to_end('Contact Type', last=False)
        item.update({'Lead Source':item["LeadSource"]})
        item.move_to_end('Lead Source', last=False)
        del item["LeadSource"]
        del item["Owner.Id"]
        if item["LeadID__c"]:
            item["Account.Id"] = item["LeadID__c"]
        del item["LeadID__c"]
    if sf_object == "Contact":
        item.update({'Contact Type':'Referral Source'})
        item.move_to_end('Contact Type', last=False)
        item.update({'Lead Source':''})
        item.move_to_end('Lead Source', last=False)
        del item["Owner.Id"]

    return item
```

For some reason, it's just not working on this Windows machine and I cannot figure out why. Is it the csv.reader() that's taking in the array for each row out of order? I need help, and quick.

Comment: can you tell the use of tag `salesforce` in your post?

Comment: We are querying the data from Salesforce and writing the results to a .CSV file and then pushing it to a target system.

Comment: I don't know if makes a difference, but I would place the line `writer = csv.DictWriter(in_file, item.keys())` _before_ the beginning of the for loop.  As it is, your recreating the `DictWriter` in each iteration of the loop.